# Https Callable Functions - Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to pass an object which contains a GeoPoint member to a firebase function. I'm currently using [Codable Firebase](https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase) to encode this object.

```
  functions.httpsCallable(functionName)
        .call(encodedObject) {_, _ in }
```

I receive the following exception: "Unsupported type: FIRGeoPoint". Any suggestion on how to pass this object with Geopoint to the function?

Comment: You can pack the data in a different object type